# how to stop BroadcastReceiver if app is closed

Tags: android, android-manifest, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I defined in my **Manifest** a Broadcast Receiver to control if the internet connection is active or not.
If there is no internet the app starts an Intent and opens a new Activity.

The problem is that if I close the app and I lose the internet connection the Activity pops up!

**How do I stop the broadcast receiver when the app is closed?**

Thanks

Comment: Umm, it sounds like your app is doing exactly what you tell it to. All receivers registered in the manifest are permanent (as far as I know). But `The problem is that if I close the app and I lose the internet connection the Activity pops up!` Isn't that exactly what your manifest says should happen?

Answer (score 0):

BroadcastReceiver is not closing. He may works even your app is closed.
Try to add special boolean statements in your onReceive method.

Sample: if app closed - don't do code in onReceive

```
onReceive(){
    if(isAppRunning){
           // do something if app is running
    }
}
```

Comment: But you should unregister the BroadcastReceiver when you're not using it.
If you don't unregister the BroadcastReceiver you quite possibly get an exception when the application registering the BroadcastReceiver is killed and in this case the Internetconnection is closed and is broadcasting that it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the broadcast receiver to act only when the activity is running, you might need to consider registering inside the activity.